# IndentationError within the timeit function

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, timeit

I want to measure a processing time of a part of my code and I used timeit function for the purpose. However it returns IndentationError from inside of the timeit function.

Here is my code;

```py
for stem, result in zip(stem_dirs, result_dirs):

        code_to_measure = '''
        print(stem, '\n', result)
        subprocess.call(['python', './a.py', "--dir_in", stem, "--dir_out", result])
        '''

        proccess_time = timeit.timeit(code_to_measure)
        print(proccess_time)
```

Here is the error I get;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code_test.py", line 115, in <module>
    proccess_time = timeit.timeit(code_to_measure)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/timeit.py", line 233, in timeit
    return Timer(stmt, setup, timer, globals).timeit(number)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/timeit.py", line 123, in __init__
    compile(stmtprefix + stmt, dummy_src_name, "exec")
  File "<timeit-src>", line 3
    print(stem, '
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

However, the timeit function in the code below still runs properly;

```py
# importing the required module 
import timeit 

# code snippet to be executed only once 
mysetup = "from math import sqrt"

# code snippet whose execution time is to be measured 
mycode = ''' 
def example(): 
    mylist = [] 
    for x in range(100): 
        mylist.append(sqrt(x)) 
'''

# timeit statement 
print(timeit.timeit(setup = mysetup, 
                    stmt = mycode, 
                    number = 10000))
```

Here is the output of the code;

```
0.002189640999858966
```

I am not too sure how to solve the issue. Please advise me if you have any suggestion or solutions on this issue.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a late reply but I ran into the same issue.

It is not possible to simply use triple-quoted strings with newlines in the timeit call. If you want multiple statements in your statement string you can separate them with a `;`.

For your code it would look something like this:

```py
for stem, result in zip(stem_dirs, result_dirs):
        code_to_measure = f"print({stem}, '\n', {result});subprocess.call(['python', './a.py', '--dir_in', stem, '--dir_out', {result}])"

        proccess_time = timeit.timeit(code_to_measure)
        print(proccess_time)
```

(Also adding the variables via format string since timeit runs in an empty environment)

The reason why the timeit call below runs is because it does not actually execute the statements in the function. All it does is create the function, which also explains why it is so ridiculously fast.

Answer (score 0):

The two ways to perform indentation is to either use whitespaces (standard norm is to use 4 whitespaces for one level indentaion), or to use tabs. Make sure you are not mixing them. Stick to one of it.

I might be able to help you more by telling exactly what is the problem if you can share your code with me as a .py file.